# Laravel Many to Many relationship only works for first record

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have 2 tables and 1 pivot table with many to many relationship. However the relationship only works for the first record, for the second record onwards, the relationship can't be detected.

These are my tables. Roles, Admins and my pivot table is admin_role.

**Model**

Admin.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Role;
use App\Notifications\AdminResetPasswordNotification;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    //Send Notification
        /**
     * Send the password reset notification.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new AdminResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Relationships
    */
    public function role() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->using('App\RoleAdmin');
    }


}
```

Role.php

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\Admin;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    public function admin()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Admin::class)->using('App\RoleAdmin');
    }
}
```

RoleAdmin.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class RoleAdmin extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'admin_role';

    protected $fillable = ['admin_id' , 'role_id'];


}
```

So the problem right now is

```
$admin = App\Admin::find(1);
$admin->role()->get();
```

When I run the above method, I can retrieve back record.

Same for this

```
$role = App\Role::find(1);
$role->admin()->get();
```

However for this,

```
$admin = App\Admin::find(2);
$admin->role()->get();
```

And

```
$role = App\Role::find(2);
$role->admin()->get();
```

There are no records.

UPDATE :  AdminRoleTable looks like this

```
id    admin_id   role_id 
1        1          1
2        2          2
```

Comment: please show your `admin_role` table.. just to be sure the record looks right..

Comment: HI I have updated a screenshot on how the AdminRoleTable looks like , thank you.

Comment: what about roles' record with id=2

Comment: If I run $role = App\Role::find(2); , it gives me back a record of editor, so it does does exist.

Comment: Can you please try put `\DB::enableQueryLog()` before and `dd(\DB::getQueryLog())` after your `->get()` and tell us the result

Comment: Guys, I manage to solve the issue, I truncated the db and tried again, it seems fine now